# WebAPI MVC Areas with same controller name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

The structure of webapi is as follows:

```
App
   -Area
       -MyArea1
         - ControllerA (Route('api/myarea1/controllera'))
       -MyArea2
         - ControllerA  (Route('api/myarea2/controllera'))
```

Problem is that the route api/myarea1/controllera and api/myarea2/controllera are not being resolved. It comes are 404.

I read somewhere we need to implement IHttpControllerSelector but not sure what is the simplest way to implement this. If there is any other way it can be done?

Any idea.

Edit:
RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Edit 2:

```
   public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
   {
        context.MapHttpRoute(
            name : "MyArea1_default",
            routeTemplate : "MyArea1{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults : new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you please post your RouteConfig file? Also your WebApiConfig

Comment: And both your controllers are inheriting from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx?

Comment: Thats correct It does

Comment: Do your areas have route/webapi config files also?

Comment: yes they have I have updated  the question with one of them the other is is similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use controllers with the same name, you need to specify the namespace for each route configuration.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapHttpRoute(
        name : "MyArea1_default",
        routeTemplate : "MyArea1{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults : new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "Your.Controller.Namespace.Here" }  
    );
}
```

For your reference:
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/01/12/ambiguous-controller-names.aspx/

Comment: That doesnt work. I have another area MyArea3 which has FooController and it works fine. I think the problem is with the same controller name in two different area which is confusion mvc routing.

Comment: Tried that but doesnt work. Also I dont know if context.MapHttpRoute() is in MVC rather then asp.net webapi as I am not been able to find that method. I have used context.MapRoute(...) but without luck.

Comment: `MapHttpRoute` is in WebApi, `MapRoute` is in MVC. When you say it's not working, what error are you seeing?

Comment: Did you find a solution @activebiz?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work. In fact this is a known issue in webapi where you cant have controllers with same name (different namespace and/or route)

Comment: Can you share a link please? Would be interested in reading more!